# Pricing of cloud storage in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have some basic pricing questions of cloud storage in GCP.

Here are my questions:

1) After the free trial period is 5 GB/month free storage only applicable for US-WEST1, US-CENTRAL1, and US-EAST1 regions and not the other US regions?

2) If I am storing 3 GB of data every day but deleting this data right after a job is completed let's say after an hour then I will have 3 GB of data in cloud storage on last day of the month. In this case how will i be charged?

1. Will all that 3 GB will get added up and i will be costed for 90(3*30) GB of data?
2. Or, will i only be charged for 3 GB?

Could anyone help me with the pricing questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Storage Costs**

As you can see on the [GCP Free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free) website for cloud storage, if you expand the card, you have 5 GB/month of Regional Storage for all US regions excluding Northern Virginia (us-east4).

You will be charged for what you have in storage of your project incrementally (for example if you add 1GB per day and keep it there, you will be charged for 1GB-Month on the end on the month -- if you have 1GB there for one day and then delete it, you will be charged roughly 1/30 of a GB-Month) to a limit of 5GB for the free tier. So 3GB will be free, however, since you will be operating a lot with that data, you will probably have operations costs associated with that.

Here you can find the [price tables](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing) on the Cloud storage documentation.

**Operations Costs**

When you operate Data on Cloud Storage, there is a cost to that, but of course, there is also a free tier, and you [Cloud Storage Always Free usage limits documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free), the operations are divided into Class A and Class B, and in you can check on the [Operations pricing section](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) under what class each operation falls, and there are different usage limits for each of them, which you can check one of the links I already shared

The pricing also depend on the kind of storage you will use, which from what you shared, I assume it will be standard.

**Network Costs**

Another cost you might have to consider is the one for Network usage, which you can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing), although this is out of the scope of your question.

**NOTE**: you can control how much you app is costing you on the [billing session of google cloud platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/unbilledinvoice?_ga=2.112539968.539155100.1582546499-1296014413.1579530907&_gac=1.250859058.1582205388.EAIaIQobChMI0IHg_p3g5wIVWuJ3Ch1drgjJEAAYASAAEgLIxvD_BwE), this could be useful if you want to give it a sample test.

Comment: You get charged not based on what is there "when billing is closed", but incrementally (e.g. 1/GB for the whole 30-day month is the same as 30GB for one day of that month).  However, in this case you are still within the free tier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @robsiemb, I had misunderstood the documentation. I have edited that information into my answer.

Comment: I made one minor clarification -- 1GB left there for a month is only 1 GB-Month, not 30 :)

Comment: If i am storing 5GB of data per month and I am not deleting, then will I exceed the data limit?